# How to run all mstests in solution on prebuild action

Tags: c#, mstest

I have solution where I have some tests.
I would like to run all tests on pre-build action and if any of the tests fails the build will show erros and not start the project.

I am using VS2010 and MS TEST.

Any idea how to do this?
thnx

Can you please post example of the command? thnx

*my tests are in testlist called uploadTests.vsmdi*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set my tfs server to run continuous integration and this gave me what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the command line statement to run mstest. 
I guess it should really be a Postbuild event rather than a prebuild, as probably your test will need the current project compiled to run. In fact I don't know if you'd be able to do it with a postbuild either if that is the case.

Why do you want this ? It sounds as it will be a bit annoying to have this constraint.

I'd recommend you try [ncrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net) if you want to have your tests running continuously as you modify code.

Answer (score 0):

> my tests are in testlist called uploadTests.vsmdi

This is not your test list. It is the metadata file where you can create your testlists. If you haven't create a list yet, double click on this file to open it, [create the testlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182462.aspx) and add the tests you want into this list. Then run the following command:

```
[MStestPath]\MStest /testmetadata:[SolutionPath]\uploadTests.vsmdi /testlist:TestList
```

- [Defining Test Lists to Group Your Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286584)